# What is the inverse of this statement

Tags: logic

What is the inverse of this statement:

The case $Q$ is true if and only if there exist $θ∈ℝ$ such that the property $P=P(θ)$ is verified.

Comment: I'm not sure if "converse" is the term you want. Do you want to know how to negate both sides?

Comment: @BrianO: Yes, I wante to negate both sides.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10435/negation-of-if-and-only-if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither "converse" nor "inverse" quite work when applied to biconditionals. To negate both sides:

$$\neg Q \iff \forall \theta \in \mathbb R: \neg P(\theta) $$

In other words, $Q$ is false *iff* for all reals $\theta$, $P(\theta)$ does not hold.