# Logical equivalence of $\forall x \ P(x) \lor \forall x \ Q(x) $ and $\forall x \ \forall y \ (P(x) \lor Q(y) )$.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

> Show that $\forall x  \ P(x) \lor \forall x \ Q(x) $ and $\forall x \ \forall y \ (P(x) \lor Q(y) )$ are logically equivalent.

I tried to consider three cases:

- $\forall x  \ P(x)$ is true,
- $\forall x  \ Q(x)$ is true or
- both of them are true. (I'm stuck here and don't have any idea).

Comment: Your second formula contains no $y$ after the quantifier?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Sorry , I edited .

Comment: Can you show us a bit more of what you've tried? The 3rd case is unnecessary. You need to show that any model that satisfies the first formula satisfies the second as well, and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [method of analytic tableaux](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux): start with the negation of

$$((\forall xP(x)\lor\forall xQ(x)))\leftrightarrow(\forall x\forall y(P(x)\lor Q(y)))\tag{1}$$

then apply a series of contradiction-hunting rules to establish that $(1)$ is what's known as a *tautology*, like so:

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with this method , can you help me please ?

Comment: First, @S.H.W, it assumes the negation of $(1)$. Then it splits into the two possibilities: when the LHS of $\leftrightarrow$ is false while the RHS is true, and *v.v.* The consequences of each possibility are explored, looking for contradictions. Four paths are made in this example. Can you spot the contradictions?

Comment: What about other possibilities ? I mean when LHS and RHS both are true or false .

Comment: Then the iff statement would be true, @S.H.W.

Comment: How we can be sure that if both of them are true or false doesn't give us a contradiction ?

Comment: Check the truth table for an iff statement, @S.H.W.

Comment: A less glib answer to your follow-up question would be that *the method assumes the negation of the iff statement* in order to find contradictions, so, by the truth table of an iff, those above are the only possibilities, @S.H.W.

Comment: This link solved my problem : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10435/negation-of-if-and-only-if                      Thanks a lot .

Comment: Excellent. I'm glad it's sorted. Don't forget to upvote & accept this answer if it does the job, then, now, @S.H.W.

Comment: I accepted the answer , thanks again .

Comment: The diagram above was generated [here](https://www.umsu.de/trees/).